# Convert ParametricPlot3D Code to Graphics3D in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a code in ParametricPlot3D that I would like to convert to Graphics3D. How would I do this?

`ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[v] (Cos[u] - 15 Cos[u]), 8 Cos[v],  Sin[v] (2 Cos[5 u] - 8 Cos[u] - 10 Cos[3 u] - Cos[4 u])}, {u, 0,  Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, MeshStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> Yellow,  Boxed -> False]`

Answer (score 0):

If I do

```
FullForm[ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[v](Cos[u]-15 Cos[u]),8 Cos[v],
  Sin[v](2 Cos[5 u]-8 Cos[u]-10 Cos[3 u]-Cos[4 u])},{u,0,Pi},
  {v,0,Pi},MeshStyle->None,ColorFunction->Yellow,Boxed->False]]
```

then it displays

```
Graphics3D[List[...]]
```

so that tells me that the result of your `ParametricPlot3D` already is a `Graphics3D`.

I am guessing that I don't understand something about what you are asking for.

Comment: Try `InputForm[ParametricPlot3D[...]]` and when it is done it should be displaying a very large block of Mathematica code. Copy that to the clipboard and then paste that into Notepad and potentially save as a file. That should be about 400 kbytes. Then exit Mathematica, restart and paste that 400 kbyte "line" of Mathematica code into the fresh notebook. It may take minutes to read that back into Mathematica. When it is finally done then position the cursor just after the closing "]" and <shift><enter> and wait a minute for it to process that and you should then see your `Graphics3D[...]` image